# Serverless offline throws an error on rejecting new Error while AWS serverless returns properly

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

Serverless offline throws an error while AWS serverless returns properly.

My code snippet :
When i try to reject certain code:

```
if(rows.length){
  reject(new Error("409"));
}
```

An error will occur on my local debugging

```
  at Query._callback (/Users/{my-user}/Private/Projects/Backend/{mywebservice}-origin/services/{user}/{user}.js:236:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/{my-user}/Private/Projects/Backend/{mywebservice}-origin/services/{user}/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/{my-user}/Private/Projects/Backend/{mywebservice}-origin/services/{user}/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/Users/{my-user}/Private/Projects/Backend/{mywebservice}-origin/services/{user}/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/{my-user}/Private/Projects/Backend/{mywebservice}-origin/services/{user}/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/Users/{my-user}/Private/Projects/Backend/{mywebservice}-origin/services/{user}/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/{my-user}/Private/Projects/Backend/{mywebservice}-origin/services/{user}/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/{my-user}/Private/Projects/Backend/{mywebservice}-origin/services/{user}/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
```

While on AWS Serverless it works just fine.

This is my current setup:

- `System : "/Users/{my-user}/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/npm",`
- `"runtimeExecutable": "/Users/{my-user}/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/npm",`
- `Serverless runtime nodejs14.x`

Comment: `at Query...` this is not an error. Let's provide more information about your error like an error message.

Comment: HEllo @hoangdv may i know what error message the response from the webservice or the logs on my local machine? Thanks